# How class object is working as interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am trying to understand MVP flow in an android example.

LoginPresenter accepts LoginView in its attachView method. But in the below example, this is passed but this passed is object of LoginActivity.
How this is working?

what if  LoginActivity implement one more interface say LogoutView, then how in loginPresenter.attachView(this) this is LoginView not LogoutView?

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginView {

@Inject
LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        loginPresenter.attachView(this); //how this ( LoginActivity 
                                         //instance )passed in here is 
                                         //working as LoginView but 
                                         //LoginPresenter accepts 
                                         //LoginView here.
                                         //Need Explaination.
    }


}


public class LoginPresenter extends BasePresenter<LoginView> {

@Override
    public void attachView(LoginView mvpView) {
        super.attachView(mvpView);
    }

}

public class BasePresenter<T extends MVPView> implements Presenter<T> {
@Override
    public void attachView(T mvpView) {
        mMvpView = mvpView;
    }
}


public interface Presenter<V extends MVPView> {

    void attachView(V mvpView);
}
```

Comment: That works, because `LoginActivity` implements the interface `Loginview`

Comment: this passed in loginPresenter.attachView(this) is instance of LoginActivity. Downgrading the question is not the solution here. Help me to explain how LoginView is LoginActivity

Comment: When you write `LoginActivity implements LoginView`, what this actually means is that a variable of type `LoginView` is allowed to reference an object of class `LoginActivity`.  That's exactly what's happening in your example.

Comment: That are Basic OO concepts. Yiou can use googel to find detailed informations about it

Comment: If LoginActivity implement one more interface say LogoutView, then how in loginPresenter.attachView(this) this is LoginView not LogoutView?

Comment: It's actually both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implements` means "can be used as".

Your `LoginActivity` implements `LoginView`, so it *can be used as* a `LoginView`.

Simple as that.

> If LoginActivity implement one more interface say LogoutView, then how in loginPresenter.attachView(this) this is LoginView not LogoutView?

If you mean something like this:

```
class LoginActivity implements LoginView, LogoutView
```

Then LoginActivity can be used as both a `LoginView` *and* a `LogoutView`. How cool is that!

Why?

Interfaces are used to define what capabilities a class has i.e. what can a class do.

Let's say `LoginView` looks like this:

```
interface LoginView {
    void login(String userName, String password);
}
```

It says that `LoginViews` must be able to `login` with a user name and password.

When you implement this interface, you must add this method to the implementing class. After you did this, your class *can be used as* a `LoginView`. Why? Because it has a `login` method!

Comment: that explains my doubt. Thank you